# Firebase duplicates presumably because of offline behavior

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have an app (Flutter / Firebase) where people save their predictions for soccer matches.

The way it works is: every person has a document per round of soccer matches.

So when saving a prediction, I check if there is a document for that person for that round, if it does, I write into it, if it doesn't I create a new document.

It was working fine until the amount of users and their circumstances increased. Now, I'm getting a few duplicates and I'm guessing it's because the person saving picks has no internet connection so it doesn't find a document and tries to write a new one.

What would be the best approach to fix this?

Designing a specific reference path for the documents?

Checking for internet connection before attempting any writes?

Or something else?

```
  Future<String> saveToFirebase() async {
     return await Firestore.instance.collection('picks')
     .add(this.toJson())
     .then((value) => Future.value(value.documentID))
     .catchError((onError) => Future.error(onError));
  }

  Future<DocumentReference> picksDocumentReferenceFor(User user, String round, String groupId, String leagueId, { bool create = false, String roundName, String seasonId }) async {
    String path = 'picks/';

    return Firestore.instance
    .collection('picks')
    .where('groupId', isEqualTo: groupId)
    .where('userId', isEqualTo: user.id)
    .where('round', isEqualTo: round).getDocuments()
    .then((value) async {

      String docPath;
      if (value.documents.isEmpty) {
        //No document found.. need to create it. 

        if (create) {
          await PicksDocument().saveToFirebase()
          .then((documentId) {
            docPath = path + documentId;
          });
        }
      } else { 
        docPath = path + value.documents.first.documentID; 
      }
      print(docPath);
      DocumentReference ref; 
      if (docPath != null) ref = Firestore.instance.document(docPath);
      return Future.value(ref);
    });

  }
```

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which any one of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Following this guidance will drastically increase the chances that someone can help you.

Comment: Thanks for that code. Now what specific line in that code doesn't do what you expect it to do? It is often easiest to show us the problem by `print`ing a value in your code, and then including the updated code, its output, and what you expected it to print in your question.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for taking a look. That's why I believe it's more a problem of my logic and not the code itself. The code works fine, and unfortunately I haven't been able to replicate the problem myself, but I do get some duplicate documents in Firebase. I'm guessing either my logic is wrong or I need to validate internet connection maybe..

Comment: Have you tried to use `.set(ID)` instead of `.add()`? this can allow you to have only one document, just need to have a rule on how the key is generated

Comment: Hi @JoséSoní in that case I would have to create the ID myself right? Instead of it being auto generated I would have to make it a mix of [userId-round-league] or something like that. I guess that could work, any idea if it would hurt the speed of my queries by not using the autogenerated ids?

Comment: yes, you would need to create the ID by yourself.  To avoid performance issues, generate or hash the keys in a way that they are uniformly distributed in the whole key domain.